# How to print/debug all jobs of includes in GitLab CI?

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci, nested-includes

In Gitlab CI it is possible to include one or many files in a `.gitlab-ci.yml` file.
It is even possible to nest these includes.
See https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/includes.html#using-nested-includes.

How can I see the resulting CI file all at once?

Right now, when I debug a CI cycle, I open every single include file and
combine the resulting file structure by myself. There has to be a better way.

### Example

Content of https://company.com/autodevops-template.yml:

```yaml
variables:
  POSTGRES_USER: user
  POSTGRES_PASSWORD: testing_password
  POSTGRES_DB: $CI_ENVIRONMENT_SLUG

production:
  stage: production
  script:
    - install_dependencies
    - deploy
  environment:
    name: production
    url: https://$CI_PROJECT_PATH_SLUG.$KUBE_INGRESS_BASE_DOMAIN
  only:
    - master
```

Content of .gitlab-ci.yml:

```yaml
include: 'https://company.com/autodevops-template.yml'

image: alpine:latest

variables:
  POSTGRES_USER: root
  POSTGRES_PASSWORD: secure_password

stages:
  - build
  - test
  - production

production:
  environment:
    url: https://example.com
```

This should result in the following file structure:

```yaml
image: alpine:latest

variables:
  POSTGRES_USER: root
  POSTGRES_PASSWORD: secure_password
  POSTGRES_DB: $CI_ENVIRONMENT_SLUG

stages:
  - build
  - test
  - production

production:
  stage: production
  script:
    - install_dependencies
    - deploy
  environment:
    name: production
    url: https://example.com
  only:
    - master
```

→ How can I see this output somewhere?

### Environment

- Self-Hosted GitLab 13.9.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I continued to search for a solution, I read about a “Pipeline Editor“ which was released in GitLab version 13.8 this year. Turns out that the feature I am looking for was added to this editor just some days ago:

Version 13.9.0 (2021-02-22) „View an expanded version of the CI/CD configuration” → see [Release Notes](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2021/02/22/gitlab-13-9-released/#view-an-expanded-version-of-the-cicd-configuration) for a feature description and introduction video.

> To view the fully expanded CI/CD configuration as one combined file,
> go to the pipeline editor’s »View merged YAML« tab. This tab displays an
> expanded configuration where:
>
> - Configuration imported with include is copied into the view.
> - Jobs that use extends display with the extended configuration merged into the job.
> - YAML anchors are replaced with the linked configuration

Usage: Open project → Module »CI / CD« → Submodule »Editor« → Tab »View merged YAML«

[image: Screenshot Pipeline Editor Merged Configuration Tab]

Answer (score 0):

GitLab 15.1 offers an altervative:

> 

> ### [Link to included CI/CD configuration from the pipeline editor](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2022/06/22/gitlab-15-1-released/#link-to-included-cicd-configuration-from-the-pipeline-editor)
>
> A typical CI/CD configuration uses the include keyword to import configuration stored in other files or CI/CD templates. When editing or troubleshooting your configuration though, it can be difficult to understand how all the configuration works together because the included configuration is not visible in your `.gitlab-ci-yml`, you only see the include entry.
>
> **In this release, we added links to all included configuration files and templates to the pipeline editor**.

Now you can easily access and view all the CI/CD configuration your pipeline uses, making it much easier to manage large and complex pipelines.

> [image: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7BNDUYfY_ok]
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipeline_editor/) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/350722).